# Update 30K rows with same value

Tags: sql

I want to use update query to Inactive around 30K parts id. is there any way i can make a single query to achieve that.

Here my table looks like

```
part id   Status
1           Active
2           Active
3           Active
4           Inactive
5           Active
```

Comment: `update ... where part_id in (.....)`

Comment: Where does this list of IDs come from?

Comment: Do I have to add all these 30,000 parts id numbers?

Comment: Do you mean in your table to inactive all active columns ?
UPDATE table SET status = 'Active' WHERE status = 'Inactive';

Comment: You can likely do it in one statement, but we don't know what criteria defines which records you are updating. What is the criteria? Which records are being updated?

Comment: If you can identify exactly the rows you want to update in a single query, then yes.  If you can't, then no.

Comment: You didn't specified update condition so your question is unclear, please fix it or it will downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table consists only of those two columns and you're wanting to update every row where `Status = 'Active'`  to `Status = 'Inactive'` then the following will work:

```
UPDATE tableName SET Status = 'Inactive' WHERE Status = 'Active'
```

However, if you're wanting to target specific records to update, you will need to know the `part id` of each record you're wanting to update because there are no other columns to narrow down the update in the `WHERE` clause.